Why is $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+c\cdot h)-f(x)}{h} = c\cdot f'(x)$?

Why is $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+c\cdot h)-f(x)}{h} = c f'(x)$? for a differentiatable function $f$?

I came across this problem and in the accepted solution, the author follows that the above is true, but I don't understand why this should be the case, since obviously $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$.

Where do you see that equation in the accepted solution? Also there is an important assumption, $f$ is convex.

Shouldn't these two be equal? $\geq$ is thus true, in the same way that $a=b$ means $a\geq b.$

More generally, given any real $c,$ $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+ch)-f(x)}h=cf'(x)$$ In your case, $c=x-y.$

@Icv I was referring to the last step of the first implication, when he takes the limit of $\theta$ and follows the inequality.

@ThomasAndrews I was unsure about them being equal or not, as I had never encountered this equality before, so I put a "$\geq$" just in case. You are also correct in that I could've simply put $c$ instead of $x-y$ and I am not sure why I didn't; regardless, I still don't fully understand why the equality holds.

$$\frac{f(x+ch)-f(x)}h=c\cdot \frac{f(x+ch)-f(x)}{ch}=c\cdot\frac{f(x+h_1)-f(x)}{h_1},$$ where $h_1=ch$ goes to zero when $h$ goes to $0.$

This is really a special case of the chain rule. If $g(y)=f(cy),$ then $g'(y)=cf'(cy),$ then write out the definition of the left side as limits when $y=x/c.$ Then $g'(x/c)$ is the limit of $$\frac{g(x/c+h)-g(x/c)}h= \frac{f(x+ch)-f(x)}h.$$

Note even though $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+ch) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h) = f(x)$, you can't replace $f(x+ch)$ with $f(x+h)$ in the original limit, since the numerator and denominator both approach $0$, giving a "$0/0$ form".
